# extracting html from cross-domains

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am using jquery to get the html from a specific domain. I know that you cant use ajax becuause of the cross-domain policy, so what i did was use $.getJSON and YQL which worked great. But this only returns the body of the html, i want to retrieve the full html document with the head tags, title tags and html tags.

Can i still do this using something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same principle applies.

If you want to fetch data then it must either be:

1. Using JSON-P
2. From your own domain (as far as the browser is concerned)

You can proxy the entire document through your own domain with a little server side programming (although you should take steps to prevent yourself from being used as a URL cloaker by spammers)

Comment: I can use .net. So with server-side code can i get the full html from any domain using the .net framework

Comment: I'd be amazed if .NET lacked the capability to make HTTP requests.

Comment: @DavidDoward, just check yeah you can retieve the full html from http requests. The only thing is more implementation to get the html serverside with using ajax to retieve the html back to the client